# How do you select/highlight a part of the chart through code? (Charts- PieChartView)

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using these classes to make charts:
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts 
.I currently have a pie chart displaying two options and I was wondering how you would highlight one of the options programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following methods to highlight part of the chart through code.

```
- (void)highlightValues:(NSArray<ChartHighlight *> * _Nullable)highs;
```

This should be used to programmatically highlight values. This DOES NOT generate a callback to the delegate.

```
- (void)highlightValue:(ChartHighlight * _Nullable)highlight;
```

highlight contains information about which entry should be highlighted.No call back to delegate.

```
- (void)highlightValueWithXIndex:(NSInteger)xIndex dataSetIndex:(NSInteger)dataSetIndex callDelegate:(BOOL)callDelegate;
```

/// Highlights the value at the given x-index in the given DataSet. Provide -1 as the x-index to undo all highlighting.

Examples :

```
 1. [_chartView highlightValue:[[ChartHighlight alloc] initWithXIndex:0 
    dataSetIndex:0]];
 2. [_chartView highlightValueWithXIndex:0 dataSetIndex:0
    callDelegate:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks works great! Here is the code in swift incase anyone wants it: `pieChartView.highlightValue(ChartHighlight(xIndex: 0, dataSetIndex: 0))`

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 4

### Charts (3.1.1)

You can choose an entry manually by `highlightValue` function.

If you want to highlight (**select**) by touch point, for example using `UILongPressureGesture`, it's possible to retrieve a potential **highlight** from chart and apply to its `highlightValue` function .

```
...
let point = gesture.location(in: chart)
let highlight = chart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(point)
chart.highlightValue(highlight)
```